# High Performance Cloning

Tags: c#, clone, il

I'm after a means of deep cloning an object graph in a perfomant way. I'm going to have multiple threads cloning a graph extremely quickly such that they can play with some state and throw away the results if they're not interesting, returning to the original to try again.

I'm currently using a deep clone via binary serialization, which although it works, isn't amazingly fast. I've seen other libraries like protobuf, but the classes in my object graph may be defined in external assemblies, inheriting from classes in the main assembly and don't wish to add any complexity in those consuming assemblies if possible.

One of the interesting things I did come across was cloning using [automatically generated IL](http://whizzodev.blogspot.com/2008/06/object-deep-cloning-using-il-in-c_20.html). It seems it's not quite finished and I've posted to see if the author has done any more on it, but I'm guessing not. Has anyone else developed or seen a more fully functional way of deep cloning via IL? Or another method that is going to be fast?

Comment: EDIT: Oops, I fail at reading.

Comment: @Tejs: he's using that, if you read the question

Comment: Do you know anything special about the graph structure?  For example, can branches have references to other branches?  Can you assume some kind of balanced, normal structure structure (example: binary tree)?

Comment: @Paul: The complete graph would have a reference across branches, although I could probably isolate this fairly easily. At that point I believe any cross references could be ignored and duplicated as they don't have any state. I might try and produce an example graph and upload it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than serialisation, I only consider three options:

- Stick with serialisation, but customise it.  This might be useful if you want to declaratively bin stuff and there are very likely performance gains to be had.
- Reflection-based object walking, in conjunction with an IL emitter such as [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/).
- Code-gen or code your own cloning by literally assigning properties to each other (we have some old code that uses what we call a copy-constructor for this, takes an instance of itself and manually copies the properties / fields across).

We have some instances of code where we control the binary serialisation so that we can serialise an interned GUID table (we have lots of repeating GUIDs and serialise very large lists over .NET Remoting).  It works well for us and we haven't needed a third party serialisation framework, however, it's hand-crafted stuff with a little code-gen.

The [CSLA.NET framework](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/) features a class called `UndoableBase` that uses reflection to serialise a `Hashtable` of property/field values.  Used for allowing rollbacks on objects in memory.  This might fit with your "returning to original to try again" sentence.

Personally I'd look further into a reflection-based (preferably with emitted IL for better performance) solution, this then allows you to take advantage of class/member attributes for control over the cloning process.  If performance is king, this may not cut it.

Comment: Adam: own cloning, although would work I feel provides quite a maintenance overhead, as does custom serialization (but +1 for the obvious suggestions). Could you give me some more details on the Fasterflect suggestion?

Comment: @Ian I suggested Fasterflect as an addition to a reflection-based solution, I believe it takes what you are trying to do in reflection and emits IL to do the task directly on first call, so subsequent calls are faster.  As for copying manually, the maintenance can be mitigated by developing a simply code-gen tool to output the copy-constructor into a partial class of the class you wish to clone.

Comment: @Ian We use a code-gen tool to walk fields/properties and output a "Read/Write" pair for serialisation and deserialisation.  The only maintenance is to make sure the tools are used when classes change.  Ours isn't for cloning however, it's for .NET Remoting support.  But the idea is the same.